# How differential equation solution constant can be rewritten?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know how to ask this question,today we had a quiz from differential equations course, so, we have differential equation to be solved: 
$$
(ye^x+y)dy=(y+1)e^xdx
$$
And I got general answer:
$$
y=\ln((y+1)(e^x+1))-1+c
$$
But, in the options there was no such answer:
[Optional Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwH6P.png)

So, I needed to simplify and make answer in the form of these optional answers, and I got this solution
$$ 
e^y=e^{c-1}(y+1)(e^x+1)
$$
But, as you can see, there is no any answer showing up there, 
so, my question is: is it possible to rewrite $$e^{c-1}$$ as $$c$$ only? If so, there is answer d) which is marked correct:$$e^y=c(e^x+1)(y+1)$$

Comment: put the exponent between   {} if the exponent is a complex expression and yes you can write it as $c$.

Comment: $e^{c-1}$ is an arbitrary constant that you can call $c$ as well. The correct answer is d).

Comment: oh thank you, so, conclusion is: constant for $$(ab+c)^C = C $$, am I right

Comment: Yes thats correct. A constant is a constant @MerdanKurbanow so $e^{c-1}=C$ Option D is correct.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{ydy}{y+1} = \frac{e^xdx}{e^x+1}$$
Integrating both sides,
$$y-\ln(y+1) = \ln(e^x+1)+c$$
Rearranging, you get
$$e^y = C(e^x+1)(y+1)$$
Here, I let $c = \ln C$ and added it in the RHS log term, after which I raised both sides to $e$. This answer corresponds to option (d)